# Export with large E instead of small e

Tags: export

If I export

```
 x = {e, a, 5.*10^-15}
Export["testx.csv", x]
```

The result will be

```
"e"
"a"
5.000000000000001e-15
```

But I'd like the result to be

```
"e"
"a"
5.000000000000001E-15
```

Needs to export “.csv” unfortunately

Comment: does it have to be .csv? Could you use `.m` instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to temporarily modify export so that it uses "E", you can do the following:

```
Unprotect[Real];
Format[r_Real, CForm] /; $Real := Block[{$Real = False},
    Format[StringReplace["e" -> "E"] @ ToString[r, CForm], OutputForm]
]
Protect[Real];
```

Then:

```
Block[{$Real = True}, ExportString[{e,a,5.*^-15}, "CSV"]]
```

> ```
> "\"e\"
> \"a\"
> 5.E-15
> "
> ```

If you want to make this more permanent, you could instead do:

```
Unprotect[Real];
FormatValues[Real] = {};
Format[r_Real,CForm] /; !TrueQ @ $Real := Block[{$Real = True},
    Format[StringReplace["e"->"E"]@ToString[r,CForm],OutputForm]
]
Protect[Real];
```

Then:

```
ExportString[{e,a,5.*^-15}, "CSV"]
```

> ```
> "\"e\"
> \"a\"
> 5.E-15
> "
> ```